# How much is a decade?

Tags: filter

Say I have low pass filter (simple circuit while the capacitor is the output.)

If I look at the frequency response at the cutoff frequency the gain is -3db. However after that the slope is -20db\decade.

I don't really undestand how much a decade is.

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_2.html

lets say I have this Lowpass filter :
meaning that the fc=159.2 Hz and if I run analise of 159Hz,1590Hz,15.9KHz  I don't get a dumping of 0.1 (-20db =0.1) ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decade_(log_scale) ?

Comment: A factor of 10. 100 Hz is a decade higher than 10 Hz.

Comment: Are you asking, why isn't the blue trace one tenth of the green trace?  You need to be farther from the cutoff frequency for the -20dB/decade to apply. You are also measuring instantaneous amplitudes, not necessarily at the peaks. Measure peak, or peak-to-peak, or RMS.

Comment: It's a high pass filter!

Comment: @Chu - yes, the schematic shows a high-pass filter. Somehow he is looking at a ratio that makes it appear to be a low-pass filter in his plots. Lots of mis-understandings here.

Answer (score 1):

"Dec" is the Latin word for "Ten". In this case, "Decade" means "ten multiples" on the frequency axis. Example, one decade in frequency would be 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100. The range from 10 to 100 contains 10 multiples of 10. Another example would be 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, and 1000. The range from 100 to 1000 contains 10 multiples of 100.

When the plot shows -20dB per decade, it means that over a range of 10 multiples in frequency, the gain will drop by 20 decibels.

Comment: The OP *had* some understanding of a decade and -20dB/decade, the four frequencies he plotted are decades apart. Unfortunately, the results of his simulation have him questioning his understanding of decade, when his problem is actually in his faulty experiment.

Comment: The original question was edited after I posted this answer